# weights and biases: binarized PR curve for multi-class problem

Tags: python

I'm using w&b to visualize results from experiments I'm running from simple transformers wrapper.  It's a multi-class label.  W&B displays PR curves by class but I need a binarized PR curve for the multi-class.  any idea how to implement this?  thanks

Comment: Did you check out this [report](https://wandb.ai/wandb/plots/reports/Plot-Precision-Recall-Curves--VmlldzoyNjk1ODY?galleryTag=custom-charts) by Stacey?

Comment: it produces PR curves for each class.  I need a binarized PR curve where all class classification results are summarized in a 2x2 confusion matrix.  e.g. TP = all y_hat are equal to labels.  looks like I need to create something customized.